# Trigger en firebird

Tags: firebird

tengo este trigger, pero quiero hacer que cuente antes de agregar para ver si el dato ya existe en la tabla para que no me lo agregue dos veces.

```
AS
begin
  if (new.cantidad <= new.catidad_minima ) then
  insert into comprar (nombre_producto ,cantidad,idcategoria)
values (old.nombre_producto,new.cantidad,NEW.id_categoria);
   if (new.cantidad >= new.catidad_minima) then
  delete from comprar a
where a.nombre_producto = new.nombre_producto;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo suyo en ese caso sería definir una **PRIMARY KEY** (PK) o un **INDICE UNICO** (NDX) por uno o varios campos y dejar que la Base de Datos realice la comprobación.

De esa forma incrementas la seguridad y la velocidad a la hora de insertar.

La propia Base de Datos devolverá un error al insertar si existe duplicado, que puedes capturar y tratar desde tu aplicación.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que decirnos qué es lo que quieres contar.
Para este ejemplo supongo que quieres saber si ya hay un registro antes de insertar el dato en la tabla comprar.

```
as
declare variable contador integer;
begin
    if (new.cantidad <= new.catidad_minima) then
    begin
        /* Cuento cuantos registros hay en la tabla con ese producto */
        contador = 0;
        select count(*)
        from comprar
        where
        nombre_producto = new.nombre_producto;
        into :contador;
        /* Si no hay ninguno inserto */
        /* Si hay 1 lo sumo a la cantidad que hay */
        if (contador < 1) then
            insert into comprar (
            nombre_producto, cantidad, idcategoria)
            values (
            old.nombre_producto, new.cantidad, new.id_categoria);
        else
            update comprar
            set
            cantidad = cantidad + new.cantidad
            where
            nombre_producto = old.nombre_producto;
    end

    if (new.cantidad >= new.catidad_minima) then
        delete from comprar a
        where
        a.nombre_producto = new.nombre_producto;
end
```